# Loading pandas with a date in between

Tags: python, pandas

I have a .csv file with a line with the date and below the data that I would like to load as a df: eg:

```
2018 - 01 - 14
Heure,Column1, Column2,....,ColumnN
15:01:02.000,50,30,...,50
```

Is there a way to add the date in the first line to the date column with a pandas.read_csv ? ( and not to parse line per line)

Thank you!

Comment: Use `pd.read_csv('filename.csv', skiprows = 1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First read the csv with `skiprows=1` argument (`df=pd.read_csv('your.csv', skiprows=1`). Then read just the first line of the csv and store it as a new column in the dataframe.

```py
with open('your.csv', newline='') as f:
   reader = csv.reader(f)
   df["Date"] = next(reader)
```

If you want it as one DateTime column, you could combine them by using ` pd.to_datetime':

```py
pd.to_datetime(df['Date'] + ' ' + df['Heure'])
```

Comment: Thanks, had to change some small details but it worked !